# Run different @Schedule-methods in parallel in one @Singleton-bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a singleton-bean which basically looks like this:

```
@Singleton
public class Timer {

    @Schedule(minute="*/3", hour="*")
    public void method1() {
        // Task may take 10 minutes sometimes
    }

    @Schedule(minute="*", hour="*")
    public void method2() {
        // This should run even though method1 is running
    }
}
```

When method1 is running I don't want method1 to be invoked again (in parallel). Thats why I use a singleton-bean. This works as expected. But I have noticed that method2 is not beeing invoked either when method1 is running. I want method2 to run even though method1 is running for a long time.

(The methods are calling methods in different singleton-beans)

Comment: Did you mean it works as expected if you have these two methods in different Singleton beans ?

Comment: No, that was just ment to describe what the actual code in these methods do to explain that they do not use the same singleton-method in some other bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create two singleton classes, one containing method1 and another containing method2. What is currently happening is that while a client is executing say method1, all methods of the singleton are locked for other clients, because the default lock type for the methods is LockType.WRITE. Since you don't want the same method to be executed in parallel you have to use this lock type, but this will lock all methods of the singleton for concurrent access. [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html) says:

> If a method is of locking type WRITE, client access to all the
>   singleton’s methods is blocked until the current client finishes its
>   method call or an access timeout occurs